# How to include and exclude a phone number string in html page on runtime using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have multiple different phone numbers in my html page.Let say numbers be like 877-413-5903, 877-413-5999, 877-413-6599. Now, I want to get all phone numbers string and replace with some other number.Let say, I want to get number 877-413-5999, 877-413-6599 and replace both number with 877-400-9797 but, I don't want to replace this number 877-413-5903.Please suggest how i can do it with Regex. So, I can include and exclude a phone number string.

Comment: Have any code to show us?  Otherwise I don't think you are going to get much of a response.

Answer (score 1):

To match any phone number of the XXX-XXX-XXXX format that doesn't match one particular specific phone number, you can use this regex (doesn't allow 877-413-5903):

```
(?!877-413-5903)\b\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}\b
```

Comment: this is just dummy numbers, actually i have only one number that don't be replace another all number are replace with one number.